# Setar valor para uma variável oracle e usala como parâmetro

Tags: sql, oracle11g

O que há de errado quando tento setar um valor para uma variável oracle11g e usá-la como parâmetro ? 
Encontrei um post com a mesma [dúvida](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/declarar-variavel-simples-e-utilizar-em-consulta-select-oracle/588624) e adotei uma das soluções porém o erro continua:

```
DECLARE
 ID NUMBER := 1888;
BEGIN     
        SELECT * FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE   ID_CLIENTE = ID;
END;
```

**erro:**

ORA-06550: line 4, column 9:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: seu código é só isso, não é parte de uma procedure ou function?

Comment: Olá! @Ricardo Pontual o código é isso mesmo ! Não é parte de procedure ou function é que eu não tenho muita familiaridade com Oracle e sim com o SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard, quando você criar uma query no Oracle, o mesmo espera que você coloque o retorno da query em uma variável, caso contrário, você deveria declarar um cursor.

A sua query está correta, mas se você pretende fazer um loop (while) nela, na verdade você precisa declarar um cursor, se você pretende apenas pegar os dados de um único cliente, aí você consegue fazer a query assim, porém será obrigado a declarar as variáveis para cada campo que deseja pegar.

Sua query com retorno para variáveis, é algo semelhante a isso:

```
DECLARE
    ID NUMBER := 1888;
    ID_QUERY NUMBER;
BEGIN     
    SELECT ID_CLIENTE INTO ID_QUERY FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE = ID;
END;
```

Dessa forma, eu pego o ID_CLIENTE do retorno da query, e coloco na variável ID_QUERY que declarei.

---

Como cursor, já é diferente, você declarar o mesmo junto das variáveis, e depois abre ele:

```
DECLARE
    ID NUMBER := 1888;
    ID_QUERY NUMBER;
    CURSOR C_CLIENTE (CLI_ID) IS
           SELECT ID_CLIENTE FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE = CLI_ID;
BEGIN     
    OPEN C_CLIENTE(ID);
    LOOP
        FETCH C_CLIENTE INTO ID_QUERY;
        EXIT WHEN C_CLIENTE%NOTFOUND
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C_CLIENTE;
END;
```

Existem outras formas de abrir o cursor, semelhante a um foreach, algo bem básico caso queira pesquisar mais:

```
--Sendo C o cursor e rec a variável dinâmica criada
FOR rec IN C LOOP  
    minhaVariavel := rec.CampoCursor;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Obrigado @Daniel Mendes ajudou muito ! resolveu meu problema !